# How would I use Google's Calendar API to dynamically create events in a SaaS app?

Tags: google-api, saas

This is a CRM-style app that can have many different organizations using it.

I don't think I can use OAuth, since these events are supposed to be dynamically created. For example, a user could make a trigger to create an event on the creation of a type of record. A user shouldn't need to be actively logged in for events to be made.

I read about service accounts, but it seems like I'd have to walk each of my users through creating a service account on their Workspace. That seems like it would quickly get out of hand.

I also don't see how I would store these service account secrets. I could switch from ENV secrets to something like AWS's SecretsManager, but is that really the only option?

Comment: Use Oauth2 store the refresh token, and use that to get a new access token at a later date.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo wouldn't that make calendar events not post if the admin user had not logged in for a long period of time?